# JavaScript function does not fire when using child model data

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working on displaying data in a separate div and when I pass my javascript function data it does not fire onclick. It works when I use data from the parent but not after I cast the data from the parent into a child and try to pass the JS function with that data.

```
##view##
@using WebApplication2.Models
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Models.OBJECT>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CompAndMon";
}
<script>
//this function does not fire when called 
    function setO(OfficeLocation,Name,Email,Phone,NumComputers,NumMonitors) {

        var text = "Primary Contact Name " + Name+"\n Primary Contact Email: " +Email +"\n Primary Contact Phone: " +Phone +"\n Number of Computers: " +NumComputers +"\n Number Of Monitors: " +NumMonitors;
        var location = "Office Location: " + OfficeLocation;  
        document.getElementById("Nametag").innerHTML = location;
        return document.getElementById("OCM").innerHTML = text;
    }
//this function does not fire when called 
    function setComputer(lastS) {

        var text = "you selected Item No: " + lastS;

        return document.getElementById("OCM").innerHTML = text;
    }
//this function operates correctly
    function setMonitor(id) {

        var text = "you selected Item No: " + id;

        return document.getElementById("OCM").innerHTML = text;
    }
    </script>  


@foreach (var item in Model)
                    {

                        if (@item.Type == 1)
                        {

                            var office = item as Office;
                            var loc = @office.OfficeLocation;
                            var Name = @office.Name;
                            var email = @office.Email;
                            var phone = @office.Phone;
                            var mons = @office.NumMonitors;
                            var comps = @office.NumComputers;
                            <p><a onlick="setO(@loc,@Name,@email,@phone,@comps,@mons)">@office.Name</a></p>
                        }
                        else if (@item.Type == 2)
                        {
                            var computer = item as Computer;
                            <p>&ensp;&ensp;<a onclick="setComputer(@computer.LastUser)">@item.Name1</a></p>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var monitor = item as Monitor;
                            <p>&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;<a onclick="setMonitor(@item.ID)">@item.Name1</a></p>
                        }
                    }
 <h2 id="Nametag" style="text-align:center"></h2>
                <div id ="OCM"class="row">
                    Select a computer or monitor and the information about the de will be displayed here.
                </div>
```

and here are the class models that the view uses 
    ##OCM.cs##
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;

```
namespace WebApplication2.Models
{
    public abstract class OBJECT
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int Type { get; set; }
        public string Name1 { get; set; }
    }
    public class Office:OBJECT
    {

        public string OfficeLocation { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public int NumComputers { get; set; }
        public int NumMonitors { get; set; }
    }
    public class Computer:OBJECT
    {

        public String LastUser { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public int NumMonitors { get; set; }
        public String TotalHDSpace { get; set; }
        public String FreeHDSpace { get; set; }
        public int NumUpdates { get; set; }
    }
    public class Monitor:OBJECT
    {

        public String Manufacturer { get; set; }
        public String ModelID { get; set; }
        public String SerialNum { get; set; }
        public int HoursON { get; set; }
        public String LastTestTime { get; set; }
        public String LastTestType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I inspect the element chrome it shows that the data is being passed the the function, but it doesn't run so I am not sure what to do. any help would be appreciated

[Here shows that the data was passed to the JS functions when I inspect the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pHVA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I misspelt onclick in the setO() call and needed to pass my razor variables to the javascript function in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You use string without quote 
setComputer('ted') or setComputer(\"ted\") and not setComputer(ted)

this is the same for email and other arguments